# Search question: dot (period) and partials

Tags: craft3, search

We have a job inventory where the jobs are being saved as entries.
When searching against jobs by keyword we search against two fields: the title and a job description field.

However we are experiencing some unusual results when using the `search` parameter to search against the term `".net"`. For example:

```
{% set results = craft.entries()
.search('title:".net" OR description:".net"')
.all() %}
```

Is there a way to use `search()` to specifically only return entries where the title or description contains `.net` as at present it is returning partial matches (eg jobs where the title or description features 'networking').

The description field is a redactor/rich text field. Would this affect it?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it will be possible using the native Craft search engine as part of the search keyword normalization process involves removing all punctuation from the keywords: https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/develop/src/helpers/Search.php#L62

It might be possible on front-end searching using something like Algolia, though:
 https://plugins.craftcms.com/algolia

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks for clarifying Brad - have worked out a solution at a plugin level basically querying the craft content table directly via a database query then passing the corresponding element IDs into my `craft.entries` call:

```
$query = (new Query())
        ->select(['elementId'])
        ->from(['{{%content}}'])
        ->where(['like','field_jobs_jobTitle',$keyWords])
        ->orWhere(['like','field_jobs_description',$keyWords]);

    $entryIds = [];
    foreach ($query->all() AS $item) {
        $entryIds[] = (int)$item['elementId'];
    }
    $criteria['id'] = $entryIds
```

Comment: PS if you are aware of a way to pass parameters eg `[':keywords' => $keywords]` into a `like` DB query then do let me know!